# implementation of a linked list in java

Tags: java

I was reading about linked lists in java , I did program this code , when I run it I get `3` as output , it should print out a reverse order of the inserted numbers as following : `10 7 3` .. what is wrong with my code?

```
public class List {
    private class ListNode {
        private int contents;
        private ListNode next;

        ListNode(int contents) {
            this.contents = contents;
            this.next = null;
        }
    }

    private ListNode head;

    public List() {
        head = null;
    }

    public void insert(int contents) {

        ListNode newNode = new ListNode(contents);
        if (head == null) {
            head = newNode;
        }

        ListNode current = head;
        while (current != null) {
            current = current.next;
        }

        current = newNode;

    }

    public void reverse() {

        ListNode current = head;
        ListNode nodeNext = current.next;

        while (nodeNext != null) {
            current.next = null;
            nodeNext.next = current;
            current = nodeNext;
        }

        head = current;
    }

    public String toString() {

        String s = "";
        ListNode current = head;
        while (current != null) {
            s = current.contents + s;
            current = current.next;
        }

        return s;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List l = new List();
        l.insert(3);
        l.insert(7);
        l.insert(10);
        l.reverse();
        System.out.println(l.toString());

    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: you never set `next` when inserting value. Using a debugger, you would have quickly found that.

Comment: you mean like this `public void insert(int contents, ListNode next) {`

Comment: How did you plan this ? Did you write what you had in mind or did you do that on paper first ?

Comment: I write what I had in mind thanks all

Comment: @jhamon thanks .. why when I write `System.out.println(l.reverse());` in the main method eclipse says : `The method println(boolean) in the type PrintStream is not applicable for the arguments (void)`

Comment: because you wrote that `reverse` return `void`. Eclipse says `println(boolean)` because it can't known what type is `void` (as it's not really a type) so it assumes that could be a boolean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private ListNode head;
private ListNode tail;
public void insert(int contents) {

    ListNode newNode = new ListNode(contents);
    if (head == null) {
        head = newNode;
        tail = newNode;
        return;
    }
    tail.next = newNode;
    tail = newNode;
}
```

Keep a tail node reference for O(1) insertion.

Your `reverse()` method is a bit wrong:

```
// this loop will run forever if there are more than 1 nodes
while (nodeNext != null) {
    current.next = null;
    nodeNext.next = current; // you lose the reference to the entire list here
    current = nodeNext;
}
```

Rewrite the function:

```
public void reverse() {
    ListNode cursor = head;
    ListNode newHead = null;

    while (cursor != null) {
        ListNode next = cursor.next;
        cursor.next = newHead;
        newHead = cursor;
        cursor = next;
    }
    head = newHead;
}
```

Doing `cursor.next = newHead`, loses the original reference to `cursor.next`. And so you need to take the reference of `cursor.next` in a temporary variable:  `ListNode next = cursor.next;`

**A print function**

```
public void print() {
    ListNode cursor = head;
    while (cursor != null) {
        System.out.println(cursor.contents);
        cursor = cursor.next;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks .. why when I write `System.out.println(l.reverse());` in the main method eclipse says : `The method println(boolean) in the type PrintStream is not applicable for the arguments (void)`

Comment: @senshinakamora Because the reverse method I have written doesn't send anything back. The type is `void`. You are passing the `void` type(which is not a type) to `println()` and there is no method in PrintStream that takes a void arguement. Eclipse assumes the first kind of println which takes boolean and so it gives that error message

Comment: I've added a print function. Call `l.reverse()` and then call `l.print()`.

Answer (score 4):

Your `insert` method doesn't connect the new node to the last node of the existing list. You have to assign the new node to `node.next` of the last node of the existing list :

```
public void insert(int contents) {

    ListNode newNode = new ListNode(contents);
    if (head == null) {
        head = newNode;
        return;
    }

    ListNode current = head;
    while (current.next != null) {
        current = current.next;
    }

    current.next = newNode;

}
```

Comment: when I wrote `current.next = newNode;` eclipse said : `Null pointer access: The variable current can only be null at this location` the code does not work thanks

Comment: @senshinakamora Did you notice that I changed the loop's condition to `while (current.next != null)`?

Comment: no I did not sorry.. now when I run it I do not see any thing in the output .. Is there any wrong with my `toString` method? thanks

Comment: @senshinakamora The problem is in your `reverse` method, which seems to contain an infinite loop.

Comment: @senshinakamora BTW, your `toString` already prints the list in reverse order. Perhaps there's no need to call `reverse`.

Comment: yes it is true. I really want to know what is the wrong with my reverse method?

Comment: thanks .. why when I write `System.out.println(l.reverse());` in the main method eclipse says : `The method println(boolean) in the type PrintStream is not applicable for the arguments (void)`

Comment: @senshinakamora Why would you want to do that? You should call `System.out.println(l);` to print the list. Your reverse method returns nothing, so it can't serve as an argument to `println`.